# Oracle 12 import - imp command

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This is how my database was exported :

```
exp system/password@host  owner=(ifs_owner,sis_owner,emu_owner) file=file1.dmp  log=file1.log  direct=Y
```

I am trying to import it using the following commands :

1) In Oracle Developer:

```
create user CLIENT_TEST identified by client_test_password;
grant connect, unlimited tablespace, resource to CLIENT_TEST;
```

2) Next, in command line:

```
imp system/sys FROMUSER=(ifs_owner,sis_owner,emu_owner) TOUSER=client_test file=e:\oradata\file1.dmp
```

This works up to a point, (some tables are imported, however it fails with the following mesages):

```
. importing IFS_OWNER's objects into CLIENT_TEST
. importing SIS_OWNER's objects into SIS_OWNER
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1435 encountered
ORA-01435: user does not exist
. importing EMU_OWNER's objects into EMU_OWNER
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1435 encountered
ORA-01435: user does not exist
. importing IFS_OWNER's objects into CLIENT_TEST
```

How can i solve the errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Use parfile. I mean create a parfile for your imp command and write to line as:

```
fromuser=ifs_owner touser=CLIENT_TEST
fromuser=sis_owner touser=CLIENT_TEST
fromuser=emu_owner touser=CLIENT_TEST
imp system/sys parfile=parfilename file=e:\oradata\file1.dmp
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parfile to set oracle exp and imp parameters, all parameters like as fromuser,touser,file and ... . I mean you should write a parfile (using vi or other linux editor tools) in a directory for example /home/oracle with name **par1** and put your parameters like below. for each user write a line:

```
fromuser=ifs_owner touser=CLIENT_TEST
fromuser=sis_owner touser=CLIENT_TEST
fromuser=emu_owner touser=CLIENT_TEST
```

and use of this parfile in imp command:

```
imp system/sys parfile=/home/oracle/par1 file=e:\oradata\file1.dmp
```